# Windows prompt/powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I wanted to custom my prompt and powershell. In tutorial I see that his prompt and powershell is different because he can open new tabs and settings option look different then my.

his:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMmgP.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAQUT.png)

and my:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/di1X4.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6v8x.png)

Somebody know why my prompt/powershell is different and how to change on this new one ?(I speciall updated to win 11...)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in git microsoft:https://github.com/microsoft/terminal.

Winget users can download and install the latest Terminal release by installing the Microsoft.WindowsTerminal package"

Provide this line to prompt or powershell:

```
winget install --id Microsoft.WindowsTerminal -e
```